# openpyxl, how to close/shutdown .xlsx file/session after saving/using it?

Tags: python, openpyxl, xlsx

As I understood, there are no such functions: **del**, clear cache or garbage in openpyxl, maybe I am wrong.
The problem I'm facing:
The problem occurs when I want to save 2nd generated .xlsx file. It somehow uses previous .xlsx file (and it's data) and can't merge some cells (from prev xlsx) since it does not have a write  attribute.

So how I can close/shutdown previous xlsx. I even tried remove xlsx file before generating new one and it also did not help!

code: (I dont have permission to post pics only links):
pic 1:[src(code, tree)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUvZ1.png)
how I am saving:

```
wb.save(filename=self.fileName)
wb.close()
```

1. [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9f548.png)
2. [class with id=1 xlsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLutX.png)
3. [class with id=4 xlsx, and my code some how wrote data from prev one(for ex: ECOLOGY 17:00-19:00) it should not work like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpOY4.png)
4. [src code is here github](https://github.com/Room-Reservation-System/backend-api/tree/master/api/xlsxGenerator)

Comment: Please do not link out to images of code/errors but try to include as much as you can in the question itself

Comment: yep, sorry but stack says that I cant upload pic since i am newbie here ( I am so sad

Comment: Please include the code in the question if you expect us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not suprised that you can't reuse the same workbook object to save a file with another name. If you need to reuse this object,  you can use `workbook_obj.save(...);workbook_obj.close();workbook_obj=openpyxl.load_workbook(...)`. I haven't tested this code, but it's my best guess.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my problem! I followed @Michael Sohnen 's advice.
But still, I'm not sure if openpyxl has a garbage-clearing feature or not, but it doesn't matter. 
 **Solution:** Instead of creating a new xlsx file, I used an existing file if it exists, otherwise I generated a new one. That's all. 
**Explonation:** As I understand it, he will download this particular file.xlsx, and openpyxl will know which file to work with, so we can be sure that we have avoided a data conflict. 
**final code:**

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
from django.conf import settings
from os import path, walk

class Base:

    def __init__(self,filename:str):
        self.fileName=filename
        self.filePath=path.join(settings.BASE_DIR,'xlsxFiles',filename)
        self.folderDir=path.join(settings.BASE_DIR,'xlsxFiles')
        self.workBook=None

    def getWorkSheet(self):
        files=[]
        for (dPath,dNames,dFiles) in walk(self.folderDir):
            files.extend(dFiles)
        if self.fileName in files:
            with open(self.filePath, 'rb') as xlsx:
                self.workBook=load_workbook(xlsx)
                workSheet=self.workBook[self.workBook.sheetnames[0]]
                return workSheet
        else:
            self.workBook=Workbook()
            workSheet=self.workBook.active
            return workSheet

    def saveXlsx(self):
        self.workBook.save(filename=self.filePath)
        self.workBook.close()
```

**old one:**

```
class Base:
    wb=Workbook()
    sheet=wb.active
```

moreover I was saving generated .xlsx in in another code.py